# How to divide string in php

Tags: php, regex, string, divider

How can I add divider `;` in the following variable which contains string

I have string like this:

```
$filename = "a.jpg3c.pngyes.jpg";
```

I would like to have something like

```
a.jpg;3c.png;yes.jpg
```

This string is created when I select multiple files to upload.

Is regex only solution in here?

Comment: and how will you be able to tell that you've got 3 filenames in there, and not two files that are (say) "a.jpg.3c.png" and "yes.jpg"? or some other combo? "a.jpg3", 'c.png', 'yes', and '.jpg'?

Comment: exactly...that is one of many problems in here...let me paste some more code

Comment: So your upload code concatenates all files into a single string without separators. Have you considered, well, not doing so in the first place? You can use a simple 3 element array.

Comment: "This string is created when I select multiple files to upload." Well, stop doing it that way. Pass it as an array instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex is not the only solution! Perhaps you can use `str_replace()` instead of regex.

```
$filenames = "a.jpg3c.pngyes.jpg";

$img_extensions = array(".png", ".jpg", ".gif");
$semicolon_additions = array(".png;", ".jpg;", ".gif;");

$newfilenames = str_replace($img_extensions, $semicolon_additions, $filenames);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

**Edit:** In your particular case, I would add in the semicolon at the end of the filename inside of your loop.

Comment: This is by far the best solution. Str replace > regex

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option using regular expressions:

```
$filename = "a.jpg3c.pngyes.jpg";
$regex = '/\.(jpg|png|gif)(?!$)/';
$filename = preg_replace($regex, ".$1;", $filename);
```